# Is it possible to disable JSF's silent failure behaviour?

Tags: jsf

When there is a parsing error in a JSF page, no error message is printed to `System.err` nor `System.out`. The affected page simply does not load. We spend about half of our working days doing trial and error in xhtml files (there are extremely obscure causes of failure, such as setting a CSS class-attribute on a `p:fileUpload`-component) and it is very inefficient (and not so fun). Can this behaviour be changed to receive useful error messages?

Comment: Have you tried checking the server logs? That's usually where it outputs stacktraces for me.

Comment: @Zyl is right, actually. Many times a JSF page is invalid and EL simply get some variable wrong and the page is simply not rendered, no errors to check anywhere. It's really annoying.

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? Younger versions of JSF-2 were certainly very lax with error reporting, but JSF is now (in v2.2) more alert with reporting errors

Comment: We are using JSF 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Developmet`. It supposes to give you better error messages.

Read this for more information: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/28/jsf-20-reminder-project-stage

Comment: That has been set up like so in the web.xml since beginning work on the project, so it does not appear to be related.